# Ionic 5 when im trying to take cordova android build this error is displaying?

Tags: ionic5

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-android@0.0.8
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\FSTECH-17\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T06_20_28_398Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your version doesn't exist. I'm using cordova-android at version "8.1.0".